# Multiple meta key and value search in the query

Tags: post-meta, meta-query, array, meta-value

I am have this following API code for $_REQUEST

```
$metakey        = explode(',',$wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['key']) );
$metavalue      = explode(',',$wpdb->escape($_REQUEST['value']) );

$meta = array();

$i = -1;

foreach ($metakey as $key) {

    $i++; 

    if( $metavalue[$i] && trim($metavalue[$i]) != "")
        $meta[] = array( 'key' => $key, 'value' => $metavalue[$i] );
    else
        $meta[] = array( 'key' => $key );

}

$meta['relation'] = 'AND';

$args = array();
$args['meta_query'] = $meta;

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

It gives the right result:

```
api.php?key=fruit,drink&value=cherry,whiskey
```

It gives the right result for `fruit -> cherry and drink -> any`:

```
api.php?key=fruit,drink&value=cherry
```

But this program do not for `fruit -> any and drink -> whiskey`:

```
api.php?key=fruit,drink&value=any,whiskey
```

How to pass the `meta_value` empty value or "any" string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don’t have any conditions for “any” as a given value in your code, so it won’t be treated as any, but as “any”.

But your code checks if given value is not empty, so passing it like so should work:

```
api.php?key=fruit,drink&value=,whiskey
```

PS. I’m not sure if that’s the best way of passing arguments to your api ;)

Comment: Thanks, `if($metavalue[$i]&&trim($metavalue[$i])!=""&&$metavalue[$i]!="any")` it is resolve.